# Как удалить все что внутри восклицательных знаков?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть код, который возвращает строку:

```
Что-то что-то
!Что-то что-то Что-то что-то!
Что-то что-то
```

Как удалить все что внутри восклицательных знаков, чтобы было вот так:

```
Что-то что-то
Что-то что-то
```

Comment: ключевые слова - "регулярные выражения"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать вот так:

```
# импортируем модуль регулярных выражений
import re
# задаем текст
text = "Что-то что-то\n!что угодно, все что ты захочешь 03245к903ушкаущцойашво мшапкуц0щйл!\nЧто-то что-то"
# используя регулярное выражение, чистим текст
text = re.sub("!.*?!\n", "", text)
# выводим
print(text)
```

вывод:

```
Что-то что-то
Что-то что-то
```

P.S. моё регулярное выражение чистит в том числе и строку, если необходимо просто удалить что-то внутри восклицательных знаков, уберем из регулярного выражения `\n`

```
import re
text = "Что-то что-то\n!что угодно, все что ты захочешь 03245к903ушкаущцойашво мшапкуц0щйл!\nЧто-то что-то"
text = re.sub("!.*?!", "", text)
print(text)
```

вывод:

```
Что-то что-то

Что-то что-то
```